# Azure DevOps - Publish artifact

Tags: devops, publish, azure-artifacts

I am working with DevOps and I have some jar files that I want to publish from my project to some artifact feed.

I checked this [task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-build-artifacts-v1?view=azure-pipelines):

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    artifactName: MyBuildOutputs
```

But I need some help how can I use it at my pipeline. Can someone help me out?

Regards

Learn to use the publish artifact task

Comment: Have you tried something in your pipeline? What is the issue/error you are facing?